# Get partial NULL when adding 2 SQL (pre 2012) select statements together

Tags: mysql

End result values are correct after NULL proving that previous data is summing correctly but showing NULL IN RESULT TABLE.

```
 `(SELECT SUM(Gm1+Gm2+Gm3) 
         FROM b_Scores L   
              WHERE Status = "" ) 
 +   
 (SELECT SUM(Gm1+Gm2) 
         FROM b_Scores L 
              WHERE Status = "3A" ) as "RTtl"`
```

[image]

As visible in table, results are controlled by the column "Status"
"3Gm Ttl" values are added together properly but shows up as "NULL".
After Status = "3A" then the results are added and showing correctly

Have tried case statement but cannot format without errors.

For Additional details have included table without code for Status (Absent) = 3A.
Code 3A indicates that Game #3 should not be included in RTotal along with "A" for absent.

Output Table without code for "3A"

[image]

Comment: Can you show CREATE TABLE, testing data and desired result?

Comment: I have inserted links to tables. Do you need something else like an excel macro file?

Comment: To assist in understanding table on how the RTtl is calculated. The ttl column is summed excluding those rows marked as A for Absent. The row indicated by 3A indicates that game 3 was absent and only games 1 and 2 should be added to the RTtl sum/